# Paypal Payflow Pro API is returning null in AVSADDR and AVSZIP for card declined transactions

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am using Paypal Pay-flow Pro API for credit card payments with the address verification service. My problem is that if the credit card transaction is declined, Paypal returns null for `AVSADDR` and `AVSZIP`. I need to use these values even if the transaction is declined.

How can I get these values?

Comment: Can you post the complete response from the PayPal here ?

Comment: Declined Transaction Response
-----------------------------
RESULT=23&PNREF=A1X07C06757F&RESPMSG=Invalid account number

                      Note that no value for AVSADDR  and AVSZIP is here.

Comment: Successful Transaction Response
------------------------
RESULT=0&PNREF=A70A7A4F7743&RESPMSG=Approved&AUTHCODE=927PNI&AVSADDR=X&AVSZIP=X&CVV2MATCH=Y&IAVS=X

Note that value for AVSADDR  and AVSZIP is here.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction id "A1X07C06757F" is not a decline . It indicates that card number you entered is incorrect . Since the card number itself is incorrect , PayPal will not send the information to the processor and therefore there is no response related to the AVS and CSC . If a transaction is declined(result=12)or successful then you will see the AVS and CSC response .